# Bind DataTable to Datagridview that already have column defined

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to Bind `DateTable` to `Datagridview` that already have columns designed using Designer in VS.
Source for DataTable is sql database.
I am trying to do this using following code which adds only blank rows in datagridview.

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;  // Disable autogeneration of columns

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(col.Name);
}
dt = get_data_table("select * from Mytable");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGridView` columns have property named `DataPropertyName` just set them to your `DataTable` column names and you are set.

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(col.Name);
    col.DataPropertyName = col.Name;
}
```

this should work.