# Fixed DataGridView data binding

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am writing an application that calculates my expanses. I have a fixed DatagridView with 12 columns (Jan - Dec) and 5 row (categories).
My Classes:

```
Month -> contains the value of all 5 categories
Year -> SortedList<MonthSet.AcceptableMonths, Month>
AnnualSpend -> SortedList<ushort, Year>
```

At start the program will parse a XML file and stores the data in the relevant classes.
Now I have the class 'Month' with 5 properties (each category one) and want to bind a specific month to the corresponding column.
I would be able to go through each cell und insert the value "manually" but i dont know if that is a good approach. Also I was able to bind all my years in a ListBox but I dont know how to bind the data (when I selected a year from the ListBox). I tried to do it the normal way but I will lose all my defined rows and it will add new columns.
I dont even know if that is working like i was thinking. If not then I propably have to go through each cell.

I hope it was understandable and someone can tell me if that is even going to work or not.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code assumes `AcceptableMonths` is an `Enum` defined as below so it can be cast from an integer.

```
enum AcceptableMonths
{
    JAN, FEB, MAR, ARP, MAY, JUN, JLY, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC
}
```

You can construct a `DataSet` from the `AnnualSpend`, and then set one of its Tables (expense of the year) as the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`. The mappings from your classes to DataSet is.

```
Month->A Column, Year->A DataTable, AnnualSpend->The entire DataSet
```

The code to construct DataSet

```
AnnualSpend annualSpend; //already populated 
DataSet dataSet;

private void PopulateDataSet()
{
    dataSet = new DataSet();

    foreach (ushort yr in annualSpend.Keys)
    {
        Year year = annualSpend[yr];
        DataTable tableOfYear = new DataTable(yr.ToString()); //as key to access the Table

        //Adding columns
        List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            columnNames.Add(column.Name);
            column.DataPropertyName = column.Name; //!!!Important!!!
            tableOfYear.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.Name));
        }           

        //Adding rows            
        DataRow newRowForFoodExpense = tableOfYear.NewRow();
        //then 4 data rows for other expense categories...
        //DataRow newRowForHouseRent = tableOfYear.NewRow();

        for (int m = 0; m < columnNames.Count; m++)
        {
            newRowForFoodExpense[columnNames[m]] = year[(AcceptableMonths)m].Food;   
            //then 4 data rows for other expense categories...              
        }

        tableOfYear.Rows.Add(newRowForFoodExpense);
        //then 4 data rows for other expense categories... 

        dataSet.Tables.Add(tableOfYear);
    }
}
```

Then set the DataSource for DataGridView from ListBox.

```
listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    ushort yr = (ushort)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[yr.ToString()];
};
```

**!!!Important!!!**

Since your DataGridView already defines 12 columns before DataBinding, you need to set the [`DataPropertyName` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17269785/815938) of each column of the `DataGridView` the same as the DataTable's column name or the binding will add new columns.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that AcceptableMonths is an enum.
I guess I could now implement a INotifyPropertyChanged but that would be no problem.
Nevertheless a very nice solution. :)
Thank you very much. It would have took ages for me to figure that out. ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. The hard part, however, is that if you bind a list of `Month` directly to the `DataGridView`, they will be added as 12 Rows, not Columns, so first you have to construct a `DataTable` that fits the "reverted" Column and Row definitions...If Month as Row and Category as Column is acceptable, you can bind directly to your `Year` class (a BindingList).

Comment: Yes I already tried it and it is working. Have to do some adjustments, but now I have a clue and know where to start. Thanks again ;)